# Assign published posts to another user automatically

Tags: posts, users, publish

Usually, I write posts as admin, as this is more comfortable from the blog administration point of view. But I want the posts to be assigned automatically to another existing user with editor privileges. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `wp_insert_post_data` for the task. Something like:

```
function assign_new_post_to_specific_author( $data , $postarr ) {

  // Where author_ID is the ID of the author you want to assign the new post
  $data['post_author'] = author_ID; 

  return $data;

}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'assign_new_post_to_specific_author', '99', 2 );
```

Tried it on [c9.io](http://c9.io) and it works, but you need to check the filter priority for yourself.

Comment: Works for the new posts and also for the re-saved. Maybe the last must be avoided, but for me is OK. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can do some check whether the post is in draft or scheduled or something like this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data - Here are all things you can access via the `$data` variable. In future you can build more flexible management system.